# Woocommerce instock args

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following line of code below but its not working.

Does anyone no the correct way to show instock products only?

I cannot seem to find anything on Google rethis

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product','meta_key' => '_featured','meta_value' => 'instock','orderby' =>'rand','order' => 'DESC');
```

**Full Loop:**

```
    <?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product','meta_key' => '_featured','meta_value' => 'instock','orderby' =>'rand','order' => 'DESC');

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
$price = $product->price;


?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">

    <div class="thumbnail Product_Box">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><?php the_title()?><br />
<span class="text-color">$<?php echo $price; ?></span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>

   <?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with that loop? What result does it give?

Comment: @Howlin I have put the full loop up - it works fine without the meta_key - Also shows products not in stock and I also have tired not using the _ and same result of nothing

Comment: have you got a funtion to pull the stock number of the item? or is it stored in post meta somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => '_featured',
    'orderby' =>'rand',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_value' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    );
```

Comment: +1 , but the key `meta_value` needs to be replaced with `meta_query`, [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If you have stock management enabled, then its as simple as ticking a checkbox :) , unless you want to go the code way.

Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory (tab) , tick the checkbox for  *Out Of Stock Visibility*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are missing close the first array:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_stock_status',
      'value' => 'outofstock',
      'compare' => '!='
    )
)
```